# Running awk file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I already have an awk file and I want to implement its function when I am trying using command window I am getting command not found in bash. What all things I can do to execute awk file.

Comment: Please list what you've already tried and the errors you got.

Comment: `awk -f scriptfile`, but it also depends on what the script is doing, whether it expects one or several input files and whether it expects certain variables to be set on the command line or in the environment.  There is no way for us to know this.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: What is the first line of your `awk` script? What is the output of `cd directory-with-awk-script; ls -l`? How did you try to run the script?

Comment: I received an awk file from my friend to run a checklist of  file name not exceeding range. I copied it to my home directory as length.awk and now trying to run on log file, as $length.awk name.log

Comment: While trying above thing I am receiving bash: length.awk : command not found

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a few things.

1. Set first line of script to `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` (see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1418245/537980)
2. Set file permission to allow execution `chmod +x awk-script`
3. Run the script e.g. if script is in current directory `./awk-script`